# Range of RowIndex not Working when trying to change the range

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to select random rows using this code:

```
Sub Randomization()
  Dim nNumber As Integer, nRowIndex As Integer

  'Generate a random number
  nNumber = Int(Rnd() * (11 - 2 + 1)) + 2

  'Go through the list
  For nRowIndex = 2 To 11
    If nRowIndex = nNumber Then
      MsgBox "The number is " & Cells(nRowIndex, 1).Value
    End If
  Next nRowIndex
End Sub
```

However, when I try to replace the range of `For nRowIndex` to, let's say, `31 To 42`, the macro is not working.

Answer (score 0):

We can easily find description of `Rnd` fnction:

> The VBA Rnd function generates a random number that is greater than or equal to 0 and is less than 1.

It implies that `Int(Rnd() * (11 - 2 + 1)) + 2` is producing random number from range from 2 inclusive to 12 exclusive, so if you change loop boundaries to 31 and 42, it will never match that randomly generated number, thus it will appear that nothing happens.

Modified code would be:

```
Sub Randomization()
  ' Integer occupies the same space in memory as Long, so we Long should be used instead
  Dim nNumber As Long, nRowIndex As Long, lowerBound As Long, upperBound as Long

  lowerBound = 2
  upperBound = 11
  ' Generate a random number from given range
  nNumber = Int(Rnd() * (upperBound - lowerBound)) + lowerBound

  'Go through the list
  For nRowIndex = lowerBound To upperBound - 1
    If nRowIndex = nNumber Then
      MsgBox "The number is " & Cells(nRowIndex, 1).Value
    End If
  Next nRowIndex
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
Sub Randomization()
  Dim nNumber As Integer, nRowIndex As Integer

  'Generate a random number
  nNumber = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(31, 42) 'Change here (Need to be same)

  'Go through the list
  For nRowIndex = 31 To 42 'Change here (Need to be same)
    If nRowIndex = nNumber Then
      MsgBox "The number is " & Cells(nRowIndex, 1).Value
    End If
  Next nRowIndex
End Sub
```